# Can't connect Websocket when using vagrant envirionment

Tags: php, linux, websocket, vagrant

I'm using `Vagrant` box using [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/), the environment is PHP 5.5 + ubuntu 12.04 + apache + mysql. My Vagrant VM ip: 192.168.11.11, local machine hosts points to `192.168.11.11 reactphp.dev`, and it works.

And, I'm using this code: https://github.com/muuknl/phprealtimechat  to test websocket.

Then I visit `reactphp.dev` in my Chrome browser, and I start server script using: `php bin/server.php`, and after I type in the username I just got the error:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.11.11:2000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

It works well when I changed the websocket ip to `ws://127.0.0.1:2000/', but why it does not work if I change to my VM's ip address?

Comment: Having the same issue and it's driving me mad. We have an Angular/Mongo builld that relies in websockets to real-time updates. We will post whatever we find this week.

Comment: Same odd situation here. Any update from you guys?

Comment: Guys did anyone found solution? I'm trying to fix same issue here with Vagrant Box.

Comment: Are you running more than one laravel apps on vagrant?

Comment: Is the network of the vagrant box a private on `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.11.11"` or are you mapping ports?

Comment: I solved this issue by applying same idea as @Michael above. In Vagrantfile I used the private network IP, and set up a host file entry on the host machine to same IP address with chosen host name for the Guest (VM) host. Thanks to at Michael.

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while I haven't used PuPHPet, but when I had troubles connecting through the port (minus port 22), I've had to issue the command `sudo ufw disable` in the vagrant machine.

If `uwf` isn't the managing firewall of your vm, try `sudo service iptables stop`, or `sudo iptables -F`.

Perhaps they've changed the behavior since then, but it's still good to try.

The SSH tunnel (over the opened port 22) might allow you to access the local port `2000`, which is proxified over. The actual port 2000 of the VM might be limited due to firewall.

Try it, and tell me if this works. If not, I'll dig in deeper.